# How to determine if this satisfiable

Tags: logic

I am given the sentence: $( A \vee B) \wedge \neg( A \implies B)$  and need to determine if it is satisfiable?

Comment: Make a truth table. It only needs $4$ rows and $3$ columns. The first column is for $A$, the second for $B$, and the third for your sentence. After you fill in the table, you want to see if your sentence is true in at least one row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given some formula $\phi$, we can determine whether or not it is satisfiable by iterating through the possible assignments for its free variables and checking whether any of them make $\phi$ true. If at least one does, then $\phi$ is satisfiable. In the case that you have here, we note that $\neg (A \Rightarrow B) \equiv \neg (\neg A \vee B) \equiv (A \wedge \neg B)$, so we can rewrite your sentence as $(A \vee B) \wedge A \wedge \neg B$. Choosing the assignment $A = \top$, $B = \bot$, we see that this sentence is true.